# How to get the user input into a dynamic char array on C?

Tags: c, dynamic, char

For example:

```
char *t;

printf("Enter the value of t: ");
```

How can I save the user input into t? What can I do next?

Comment: Do you want to read a string?

Comment: Does the dynamic array need to be the exact size of the input?

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, and put it on t, without prevously knowing the lenght of it.

Comment: Time to get out that C book and learn the language.